# Visual Studio 2010 Crystal Report Blank / Empty / Not Displaying. No On-Screen Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I just uploaded my crystal report which is working fine on development PC, but as soon I uploaded it on server it just not displaying.

No error / no bar nothing.

Please help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the query is returning 0 results then it's possible to have the entire report suppressed in this case (option can be found under File -> Report Options -> "Suppress Printing if No Records" checkbox). I've seen it do weird things with this enabled while viewing outside of CR.

Comment: Hi, I am just displaying Date and Time to check if reports are working or not

Comment: Crystal will still suppress the entire report if there are no database references, as would be the case if you were just trying to display the current date/time (given that the above-mentioned check box is checked, of course)